# Configure Postfix to forward email

Tags: postfix, mac-osx-server

I just signed up for macminicolo.net and am trying to get it configured. I need to setup the server so that it will forward specific email to specific addresses (forwarder), as well as all addresses for a domain to a specific address (default address). From what I can tell: you cannot do this in the GUI server app, but you can manually change the config files without messing with the Server apps settings.

You can see my main.cf and virtual files for Postfix (with domains and addresses redacted) here: https://gist.github.com/davbeck/31f75e667be9dbe9f0ef

Following the instructions here: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding

I added the following to main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/virtual
```

And the following to virtual:

```
her@mydomain.com      address1@gmail.com
@mydomain.com         address2@gmail.com
```

I then ran the following in terminal:

```
sudo postmap /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/virtual
sudo postfix reload
```

However, when I try to send email to these addresses, I get `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table` back from the server

As a side note, I could swear I saw a Mac GUI for configuring server settings like this before, but can't for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the path to the virtual file was wrong. Should have been `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/virtual`, not `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/virtual`.